# Creating variables and reusing within a mysql update query? possible?

Tags: mysql, variables, sql-like

I am struggling with this query and want to know if I am wasting my time and need to write a php script or is something like the following actually possible?

```
UPDATE my_table 
SET @userid = user_id 
AND SET filename('http://pathto/newfilename_'@userid'.jpg')
FROM my_table 
WHERE filename 
LIKE '%_%' AND filename 
LIKE '%jpg'AND filename 
NOT LIKE 'http%';
```

Basically I have 700 odd files that need renaming in the database as they do not match the filenames as I am changing system, they are called in the database.
The format is `2_gfhgfhf.jpg` which translates to `userid_randomjumble.jpg`

But not all files in the database are in this format only about 700 out of thousands. So I want to identify names that contain `_`  but don't contain `http` (thats the correct format that I don't want to touch).

I can do that fine but now comes the tricky bit!!

I want to replace that file name `userid_randomjumble.jpg` with `http://pathto/filename_userid.jpg` So I want to set the column user_id in that row to a variable and insert it into my new filename.

The above doesn't work for obvious reasons but I am not sure if there is a way round what I'm trying to do. I have no idea if it's possible? Am I wasting my time with this and should I turn to PHP with mysql and stop being lazy? Or is there a way to get this to work?

Comment: `$sql="SELECT user_id FROM my_table WHERE filename LIKE '%_%' AND filename LIKE     '%jpg' AND filename NOT LIKE 'http%'";

    $freetplquery=mysql_query($sql);
    while ( $update = mysql_fetch_array($freetplquery) ){ 
    $userid=$update["user_id"];
    mysql_query("UPDATE my_table SET     user_avatar='http://pathto/newfilename_".$userid.".jpg' WHERE     user_id=".$userid."");}`




Wrote the script while I was waiting as above so its all sorted now thanks. However Im still quite interested if its possible without using PHP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can do it using straightforward SQL:

```
UPDATE my_table 
SET filename = CONCAT('http://pathto/newfilename_', userid, '.jpg')
WHERE filename LIKE '%\_%jpg'
AND filename NOT LIKE 'http%';
```

Notes:

- No need for variables. Any columns of rows being updated may be referenced
- In mysql, use `CONCAT()` to add text values together
- With `LIKE`, an underscore (`_`) has a special meaning - it means "any single character". If you want to match a literal underscore, you must escape it with a backslash (`\`)
- Your two `LIKE` predicates may be safely merged into one for a simpler query

Comment: Thats great thanks, bit late as I used php in the end but very handy for future reference. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible without the php. Here is a simple example

```
SET @a:=0;
SELECT * FROM table WHERE field_name = @a;
```

Comment: That will literally match the string `@a`. You mean `WHERE field_name = @a`